# How to get a dictionary from Scrapy results

Tags: python, scrapy

I need to get a list of python dictionaries from Scrapy results.

The HTML/JS code contains this section:

```
window.Matches =  [
    {
        matchId: 402404,
        leagueId: 1087,
        leagueName: "אלוף האלופים",
        leagueURL: "https://www.one.co.il/Soccer/league/1087",
        isLeagueLinkable: true,
        round: 1,
        roundName: "- משחק 1",
        date: new Date("2020-08-08T20:15:00"),
        isTimeSeted: true,
        isHaveScore:true,
        dateDay: "שבת",
        homeId: 22,
        homeName: "הפועל ב\"ש",
        homeURL: "https://www.one.co.il/Soccer/team/22",
        homeScore: 0,
        guestId: 3,
        guestName: "מכבי ת\"א",
        guestURL: "https://www.one.co.il/Soccer/team/3",
        guestScore: 2,
        arenaURL: "https://www.one.co.il/Article/20-21/1,1087,3,0/364600.html"
    },{
        matchId: 402405,
        leagueId: 1087,
        leagueName: "אלוף האלופים",
        leagueURL: "https://www.one.co.il/Soccer/league/1087",
        isLeagueLinkable: true,
        round: 2,
        roundName: "- גומלין",
        date: new Date("2020-08-13T20:30:00"),
        isTimeSeted: true,
        isHaveScore:true,
        dateDay: "חמישי",
        homeId: 3,
        homeName: "מכבי ת\"א",
        homeURL: "https://www.one.co.il/Soccer/team/3",
        homeScore: 2,
        guestId: 22,
        guestName: "הפועל ב\"ש",
        guestURL: "https://www.one.co.il/Soccer/team/22",
        guestScore: 0,
        arenaURL: "https://www.one.co.il/Article/20-21/1,1087,3,0/364952.html"
    }];
```

I've tried to do as follow:

```
import scrapy
import json

class One(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "one"

    start_urls = [
        "https://www.one.co.il/Soccer/team/3/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        resp = response.xpath('/html/head/script[3]/text()').extract_first()
        yield{
            'game': resp
        }
```

But the outcome looks like a big unreadable string as follows:

```
[
{"game": "\r\n    window.Matches =  [\r\n        {\r\n            matchId: 402404,\r\n            leagueId: 1087,\r\n            leagueName: \"\u05d0\u05dc\u05d5\u05e3 \u05d4\u05d0\u05dc\u05d5\u05e4\u05d9\u05dd\",\r\n            leagueURL: \"https://www.one.co.il/Soccer/league/1087\",\r\n            isLeagueLinkable: true,\r\n            round: 1,\r\n            roundName: \"- \u05de\u05e9\u05d7\u05e7 1\",\r\n            date: new Date(\"2020-08-08T20:15:00\"),\r\n            isTimeSeted: true,\r\n            isHaveScore:true,\r\n            dateDay: \"\u05e9\u05d1\u05ea\",\r\n            homeId: 22,\r\n            homeName: \"\u05d4\u05e4\u05d5\u05e2\u05dc \u05d1\\\"\u05e9\",\r\n            homeURL: \"https://www.one.co.il/Soccer/team/22\",\r\n            homeScore: 0,\r\n            guestId: 3,\r\n            guestName: \"\u05de\u05db\u05d1\u05d9 \u05ea\\\"\u05d0\",\r\n            guestURL: \"https://www.one.co.il/Soccer/team/3\",\r\n            guestScore: 2,\r\n            arenaURL: \"https://www.one.co.il/Article/20-21/1,1087,3,0/364600.html\"\r\n        },{\r\n            matchId: 402405,\r\n            leagueId: 1087,\r\n            leagueName: \"\u05d0\u05dc\u05d5\u05e3 \u05d4\u05d0\u05dc\u05d5\u05e4\u05d9\u05dd\",\r\n            leagueURL: \"https://www.one.co.il/Soccer/league/1087\",\r\n            isLeagueLinkable: true,\r\n            round: 2,\r\n            roundName: \"- \u05d2\u05d5\u05de\u05dc\u05d9\u05df\",\r\n            date: new Date(\"2020-08-13T20:30:00\"),\r\n            isTimeSeted: true,\r\n            isHaveScore:true,\r\n            dateDay: \"\u05d7\u05de\u05d9\u05e9\u05d9\",\r\n            homeId: 3,\r\n            homeName: \"\u05de\u05db\u05d1\u05d9 \u05ea\\\"\u05d0\",\r\n            homeURL: \"https://www.one.co.il/Soccer/team/3\",\r\n            homeScore: 2,\r\n            guestId: 22,\r\n            guestName: \"\u05d4\u05e4\u05d5\u05e2\u05dc \u05d1\\\"\u05e9\",\r\n            guestURL: \"https://www.one.co.il/Soccer/team/22\",\r\n            guestScore: 0,\r\n            arenaURL: \"https://www.one.co.il/Article/20-21/1,1087,3,0/364952.html\"\r\n        },{\r\n            matchId: 405477,\r\n            leagueId: 22,\r\n            leagueName: \"\u05de\u05d5\u05e7\u05d3\u05de\u05d5\u05ea \u05dc\u05d9\u05d2\u05ea \u05d4\u05d0\u05dc\u05d5\u05e4\u05d5\u05ea\",\r\n            leagueURL: \"\",\r\n            isLeagueLinkable: false,\r\n            round: 1,\r\n            roundName: \"- \u05e1\u05d9\u05d1\u05d5\u05d1 \u05e8\u05d0\u05e9\u05d5\u05df\",\r\n            date: new Date(\"2020-08-19T20:00:00\"),\r\n            isTimeSeted: true,\r\n            isHaveScore:true,\r\n            dateDay: \"\u05e8\u05d1\u05d9\u05e2\u05d9\",\r\n            homeId: 3,\r\n            homeName: \"\u05de\u05db\u05d1\u05d9 \u05ea\\\"\u05d0\",\r\n            homeURL: \"\",\r\n            homeScore: 2,\r\n            guestId: 5590,\r\n            guestName: \"\u05e8\u05d9\u05d2\u05d4\",\r\n            guestURL: \"\",\r\n            guestScore: 0,\r\n            arenaURL: \"https://www.one.co.il/Article/20-21/1,1,3,63766/365369.html\"\r\n        },{\r\n            matchId: 406083,\r\n            leagueId: 667,\r\n            leagueName: \"\u05d2\u05d1\u05d9\u05e2 \u05d4\u05d8\u05d5\u05d8\u05d5\",\r\n            leagueURL: \"https://www.one.co.il/Soccer/league/667\",\r\n            isLeagueLinkable: true,\r\n            round: 4,\r\n            roundName: \"- \u05d2\u05de\u05e8\",\r\n            date: new Date(\"2020-08-22T20:30:00\"),\r\n            isTimeSeted: true,\r\n            isHaveScore:true,\r\n            dateDay: \"\u05e9\u05d1\u05ea\",\r\n            homeId: 17,\r\n            homeName: \"\u05d1\u05e0\u05d9 \u05e1\u05db\u05e0\u05d9\u05df\",\r\n            homeURL: \"https://www.one.co.il/Soccer/team/17\",\r\n            homeScore: 0,\r\n            guestId: 3,\r\n            guestName: \"\u05de\u05db\u05d1\u05d9 \u05ea\\\"\u05d0\",\r\n            guestURL: \"https://www.one.co.il/Soccer/team/3\",\r\n            guestScore: 2,\r\n            arenaURL: \"https://www.one.co.il/Article/20-21/1,667,3,0/365537.html\"\r\n        },{\r\n            matchId: 406275,\r\n            leagueId: 22,\r\n            leagueName: \"\u05de\u05d5\u05e7\u05d3\u05de\u05d5\u05ea \u05dc\u05d9\u05d2\u05ea \u05d4\u05d0\u05dc\u05d5\u05e4\u05d5\u05ea\",\r\n            leagueURL: \"\",\r\n            isLeagueLinkable: false,\r\n            round: 2,\r\n            roundName: \"\u05e1\u05d9\u05d1\u05d5\u05d1 \u05e9\u05e0\u05d9\",\r\n            date: new Date(\"2020-08-26T19:00:00\"),\r\n            isTimeSeted: true,\r\n            isHaveScore:true,\r\n            dateDay: \"\u05e8\u05d1\u05d9\u05e2\u05d9\",\r\n            homeId: 5415,\r\n            homeName: \"\u05e1\u05d5\u05d3\u05d5\u05d1\u05d4\",\r\n            homeURL: \"\",\r\n            homeScore: 0,\r\n            guestId: 3,\r\n            guestName: \"\u05de\u05db\u05d1\u05d9 \u05ea\\\"\u05d0\",\r\n            guestURL: \"\",\r\n            guestScore: 3,\r\n            arenaURL: \"https://www.one.co.il/Article/20-21/1,22,3,0/365806.html\"\r\n        },{\r\n            matchId: 402498,\r\n            leagueId: 1,\r\n            leagueName: \"\u05dc\u05d9\u05d2\u05ea \u05d4\u05e2\u05dc\",\r\n            leagueURL: \"https://www.one.co.il/Soccer/league/1\",\r\n            isLeagueLinkable: true,\r\n            round: 1,\r\n            roundName: \"\u05de\u05d7\u05d6\u05d5\u05e8 1\",\r\n            date: new Date(\"2020-08-30T21:00:00\"),\r\n            isTimeSeted: true,\r\n            isHaveScore:true,\r\n            dateDay: \"\u05e8\u05d0\u05e9\u05d5\u05df\",\r\n            homeId: 3,\r\n            homeName: \"\u05de\u05db\u05d1\u05d9 \u05ea\\\"\u05d0\",\r\n            homeURL: \"https://www.one.co.il/Soccer/team/3\",\r\n            homeScore: 1,\r\n            guestId: 10,\r\n            guestName: \"\u05de\u05db\u05d1\u05d9 \u05e4\\\"\u05ea\",\r\n            guestURL: \"https://www.one.co.il/Soccer/team/10\",\r\n            guestScore: 2,\r\n            arenaURL: \"https://www.one.co.il/Article/20-21/1,1,1,0/366079.html\"\r\n        },{\r\n            matchId: 402504,\r\n            leagueId: 1,\r\n            leagueName: \"\u05dc\u05d9\u05d2\u05ea \u05d4\u05e2\u05dc\",\r\n            leagueURL: \"https://www.one.co.il/Soccer/league/1\",\r\n            isLeagueLinkable: true,\r\n            round: 2,\r\n            roundName: \"\u05de\u05d7\u05d6\u05d5\u05e8 2\",\r\n            date: new Date(\"2020-09-12T20:30:00\"),\r\n            isTimeSeted: true,\r\n            isHaveScore:true,\r\n            dateDay: \"\u05e9\u05d1\u05ea\",\r\n            homeId: 11,\r\n            homeName: \"\u05d1\u05e0\u05d9 \u05d9\u05d4\u05d5\u05d3\u05d4\",\r\n            homeURL: \"https://www.one.co.il/Soccer/team/11\",\r\n            homeScore: 2,\r\n            guestId: 3,\r\n            guestName: \"\u05de\u05db\u05d1\u05d9 \u05ea\\\"\u05d0\",\r\n            guestURL: \"https://www.one.co.il/Soccer/team/3\",\r\n            guestScore: 2,\r\n            arenaURL: \"https://www.one.co.il/Article/20-21/1,1,3,0/366927.html\"\r\n        },{\r\n            matchId: 408093,\r\n            leagueId: 22,\r\n            leagueName: \"\u05de\u05d5\u05e7\u05d3\u05de\u05d5\u05ea \u05dc\u05d9\u05d2\u05ea \u05d4\u05d0\u05dc\u05d5\u05e4\u05d5\u05ea\",\r\n            leagueURL: \"\",\r\n            isLeagueLinkable: false,\r\n            round: 3,\r\n            roundName: \"- \u05e1\u05d9\u05d1\u05d5\u05d1 \u05e9\u05dc\u05d9\u05e9\u05d9\",\r\n            date: new Date(\"2020-09-16T20:00:00\"),\r\n            isTimeSeted: true,\r\n            isHaveScore:true,\r\n            dateDay: \"\u05e8\u05d1\u05d9\u05e2\u05d9\",\r\n            homeId: 3,\r\n            homeName: \"\u05de\u05db\u05d1\u05d9 \u05ea\\\"\u05d0\",\r\n            homeURL: \"\",\r\n            homeScore: 1,\r\n            guestId: 5580,\r\n            guestName: \"\u05d3\u05d9\u05e0\u05de\u05d5 \u05d1\u05e8\u05e1\u05d8\",\r\n            guestURL: \"\",\r\n            guestScore: 0,\r\n            arenaURL: \"https://www.one.co.il/Article/20-21/1,1,3,0/367232.html\"\r\n        },{\r\n            matchId: 409037,\r\n            leagueId: 22,\r\n            leagueName: \"\u05de\u05d5\u05e7\u05d3\u05de\u05d5\u05ea \u05dc\u05d9\u05d2\u05ea \u05d4\u05d0\u05dc\u05d5\u05e4\u05d5\u05ea\",\r\n            leagueURL: \"\",\r\n            isLeagueLinkable: false,\r\n            round: 4,\r\n            roundName: \"- \u05e4\u05dc\u05d9\u05d9\u05d0\u05d5\u05e3 \u05de\u05e9\u05d7\u05e7 1\",\r\n            date: new Date(\"2020-09-22T22:00:00\"),\r\n            isTimeSeted: true,\r\n            isHaveScore:true,\r\n            dateDay: \"\u05e9\u05dc\u05d9\u05e9\u05d9\",\r\n            homeId: 3,\r\n            homeName: \"\u05de\u05db\u05d1\u05d9 \u05ea\\\"\u05d0\",\r\n            homeURL: \"\",\r\n            homeScore: 1,\r\n            guestId: 5120,\r\n            guestName: \"\u05e8\u05d3 \u05d1\u05d5\u05dc \u05d6\u05dc\u05e6\u05d1\u05d5\u05e8\u05d2\",\r\n            guestURL: \"\",\r\n            guestScore: 2,\r\n            arenaURL: \"https://www.one.co.il/Article/20-21/1,22,3,0/367637.html\"
```

Can anyone please tell me how to make from those details a valid list of python dictionaries with scrapy?:

```
[{
    matchId: 402404,
    leagueId: 1087,
    leagueName: "אלוף האלופים",
    leagueURL: "https://www.one.co.il/Soccer/league/1087",
    isLeagueLinkable: true,
    round: 1,
    roundName: "- משחק 1",
    date: new Date("2020-08-08T20:15:00"),
    isTimeSeted: true,
    isHaveScore:true,
    dateDay: "שבת",
    homeId: 22,
    homeName: "הפועל ב\"ש",
    homeURL: "https://www.one.co.il/Soccer/team/22",
    homeScore: 0,
    guestId: 3,
    guestName: "מכבי ת\"א",
    guestURL: "https://www.one.co.il/Soccer/team/3",
    guestScore: 2,
    arenaURL: "https://www.one.co.il/Article/20-21/1,1087,3,0/364600.html"
},{
    matchId: 402405,
    leagueId: 1087,
    leagueName: "אלוף האלופים",
    leagueURL: "https://www.one.co.il/Soccer/league/1087",
    isLeagueLinkable: true,
    round: 2,
    roundName: "- גומלין",
    date: new Date("2020-08-13T20:30:00"),
    isTimeSeted: true,
    isHaveScore:true,
    dateDay: "חמישי",
    homeId: 3,
    homeName: "מכבי ת\"א",
    homeURL: "https://www.one.co.il/Soccer/team/3",
    homeScore: 2,
    guestId: 22,
    guestName: "הפועל ב\"ש",
    guestURL: "https://www.one.co.il/Soccer/team/22",
    guestScore: 0,
    arenaURL: "https://www.one.co.il/Article/20-21/1,1087,3,0/364952.html"
}];
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already done most of the work. All you need to do is to use regex to fetch the exact variable's value and then since it is javascript you cannot use `json.loads()` directy. Instead you will need to evaluate it as js.

Here is the slightly modified version of the code that should work:

```
script = response.xpath('/html/head/script[3]/text()').re_first('(?s).*?window.Matches.*?(\[.*\]);')
```

This should give you the exact value of the variable. Now you just have to evaluate it. For this I will be using `js2py` library.

```
context = js2py.EvalJs({})
context.execute(f'var matches = {script}'}
result = context.to_dict()
yield {'game': result['matches']}
```

Just a side note, using indexing in xpaths is not a good try. `Contains` would be much more secure.

Comment: Hi @Abbas Maalik Wattoo 
Thank you, Now I have another problem, for the code you posted I'm getting the error:

`js2py.internals.simplex.JsException: TypeError: Could not parse date 2020-08-08T20:15:00 - unsupported date format. Currently only supported format is RFC3339 utc. Sorry!`

do you know what is the solution for that?

Comment: Yes, this is happening because there is no timezone info at the end of time str. I cannot think of an elegant solution for now but here is a quick fix that will fix your issue. `script = re.sub('(Date\(".*?)"', '\\1Z"', script)` This will add UTC timezone Z at the end and the issue will be fixed.